# How to get dummy columns from a scipy sparse csr_matrix

Tags: python, scipy, sklearn-pandas, nlp

I have an NLP problem where I'm attempting to feature engineer dummy columns using vectorized text.

I have a scipy.sparse.csr.csr.matrix called 'descriptions_test'

```
descriptions_test.shape
(54504, 19574)
```

I know it has the shape to get dummy columns but when I run

```
dummy_description = pd.get_dummies(descriptions_test)
```

I get this TypeError
`TypeError: sparse matrix length is ambiguous; use getnnz() or shape[0]`

Is there a quick work around or will I need to convert the scipy matrix to a DataFrame?

Comment: `dummy columns` is a `pandas` concept; it's not present in `numpy`, nor in the `sparse` matrices that are modeled on `numpy`.

Comment: Your sparse matrix is 2d.  `descriptions_test.toarray()` would produce a numpy 2d array (if it doesn't raise a Memory Error).  `pd.get_dummies` complains if I give it a 2d array, saying `data must be 1d`.